# Hotkey to stop script - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Am trying to create a hotkey to stop my script, this is my code so far.

```
import time
import keyboard

running = True

def stop(event):  
    global running
    running = False
    print("stop")

  
# press ctrl+esc to stop the script 
keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+esc", lambda: stop)
  
while running:
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Hello")
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: typo: change to `keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+esc", stop)`

Comment: Hi eyllanesc, When I replace that line it shows this: TypeError: stop() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

Comment: then change to `def stop(): `

Comment: thanks for your help eyllanesc, it worked but after "print("stop")" does not return to my console, should I import sys and then use sys.exit()?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add_hotkey expects a callback as the second argument, so you must pass it the stop function, on the other hand, when the callback is invoked, no event is passed.

A better solution than using a boolean variable is to use threading.Event since this is thread-safe since the callback is invoked in a secondary thread.

```py
import threading
import time

import keyboard


event = threading.Event()

def stop():
    event.set()
    print("stop")

keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+esc", stop)

while not event.is_set():
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Hello")
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate your help eyllanesc!